# How to avoid chatty interfaces

Tags: c#, design, scalability, server-side

**Background:**
I am designing a server application and creating separate dll's for different subsystems. To simplify things, let's say I have two subsystems: 1) `Users` 2) `Projects`

Users's public interface has a method like:

```
IEnumerable<User> GetUser(int id);
```

And Projects's public interface has a method like:

```
IEnumerable<User> GetProjectUsers(int projectId);
```

So, for example, when we need to display the users for a certain project, we can call `GetProjectUsers` and that will give back objects with sufficient info to show in a datagrid or similar.

**Problem:**
Ideally, the `Projects` subsystem shouldn't also store user info and it should just store Ids of the users participating in a project. In order to serve the `GetProjectUsers`, it needs to call `GetUser` of the `Users` system for each user id stored in its own database. However, this requires a lot of separate `GetUser` calls, causing a lot of separate sql queries inside the `User` subsystem. I haven't really tested this but having this chatty design will affect the scalability of the system.

If I put aside the separation of the subsystems, I *could* store all info in a single schema accessable by both systems and `Projects` could simply do a `JOIN` to get all project users in a single query. `Projects` would also need to know how to generate `User` objects from the query results. But this breaks the separation which has many advantages.

**Question:**
Can anyone suggest a way to keep the separation while avoiding all these individual `GetUser` calls during `GetProjectUsers`?

---

For example, one I idea I had was for Users to give external systems the ability to "tag" users with a label-value pair, and to request users with a certain value, e.g.:

```
void AddUserTag(int userId, string tag, string value);
IEnumerable<User> GetUsersByTag(string tag, string value);
```

Then the Projects system could tag each user as they are added to the project:

```
AddUserTag(userId,"project id", myProjectId.ToString());
```

and during GetProjectUsers, it could request all the project users in a single call:

```
var projectUsers = usersService.GetUsersByTag("project id", myProjectId.ToString());
```

the part I'm not sure about this is: yes, Users is agnostic of projects but really the information about project membership is stored in the Users system, not Projects. I just doesn't feel natural so I'm trying to determine if there's a big disadvantage here that I'm missing.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

What is missing in your system is the cache.

You say:

> However, this requires a lot of separate `GetUser` calls, causing a lot of separate sql queries inside the `User` subsystem.

The number of calls to a method doesn't have to be the same as the number of SQL queries. You get the information about the user once, why would you *query* for the same information again if it didn't change? Very probably, you may even cache all the users in memory, which would result in zero SQL queries (unless a user changes).

On the other hand, by making `Projects` subsystem query both the projects and the users with an `INNER JOIN`, you introduce an additional issue: you are querying the same piece of information in two different locations in your code, making cache invalidation extremely difficult. As a consequence:

- Either you won't introduce cache at all any time later,
- Or you will spend weeks or months studying what should be invalidated when a piece of information changes,
- Or you will add cache invalidation in straightforward locations, forgetting the other ones and resulting in difficult to find bugs.

---

Rereading your question, I notice a keyword I missed the first time: *scalability*. As a rule of thumb, you may follow the next pattern:

1. Ask yourself whether the system is slow (i.e. it violates a non-functional requirement of performance, or is simply a nightmare to use).

   If the system is *not* slow, don't bother about performance. Bother about clean code, readability, maintainability, testing, branch coverage, clean design, detailed and easy to understand documentation, good code comments.
2. If yes, search for the bottleneck. You do that not by guessing, but by **profiling**. By profiling, you determine the exact location of the bottleneck (given that when you *guess*, you may nearly every time get it wrong), and may now focus on that part of the code.
3. Once the bottleneck found, search for solutions. You do that by guessing, benchmarking, profiling, writing alternatives, understanding compiler optimizations, understanding optimizations that are up to you, asking questions on Stack Overflow and moving to low-level languages (including Assembler, when necessary).

What is the actual issue with `Projects` subsystem asking for info to `Users` subsystem?

The eventual future scalability issue? This is not an issue. Scalability may become a nightmare if you start merging everything into one monolithic solution or querying for the same data from multiple locations (as explained below, because of the difficulty to introduce cache).

If there is *already* a noticeable performance issue, then, step 2, search for the bottleneck.

If it appears that, indeed, the bottleneck exists and is due to the fact that `Projects` requests for users through `Users` subsystem (and is situated at database querying level), only then should you search for an alternative.

The most common alternative would be to implement caching, drastically reducing the number of queries. If you're in a situation where caching doesn't help, than further profiling may show you that you need to reduce the number of queries, or add (or remove) database indexes, or throw more hardware, or redesign completely the whole system.

Comment: Unless I am misunderstanding you, you're saying "keep the individual GetUser calls, but use caching to avoid db roundtrips".

Comment: @ErenErsönmez: `GetUser`, instead of querying the database, will look in the cache. This means that it doesn't actually matter how many times you'll call `GetUser`, since it will load data from memory instead of database (unless the cache have been invalidated).

Comment: this is a good suggestion, given I haven't done a good job highlighting the main problem, which is "to get rid of the chattiness without merging systems into a single system". My example of Users and Projects would naturally lead you to believe there are a relatively small number of and rarely changing users. Maybe a better example would have been Documents and Projects. Imagine you have a couple million documents, thousands being added everyday and the Project system uses the Document system to store its documents. Would you still recommend caching then?  Probably no, right?

Comment: @ErenErsönmez: the more data you have, the more critical caching appears. As a rule of thumb, compare the number of reads to the number of writes. If "thousands" of documents are added per day and there are millions of `select` queries per day, you'd better using caching. On the other hand, if you're adding billions of entities to a database but only get a few thousands of `select`s with very selective `where`s, caching may not be that useful.

Comment: you're probably right -- I'm probably trying to fix a problem I don't have yet. I will probably implement as is and try to improve later if needed. If caching isn't appropriate because, e.g., entities are likely to be read only 1-2 times after being added, do you think the possible I solution I appended to the question might work? Do you see a huge problem with that?

Comment: A huge problem with that is data duplication. This is a case where it's easy to have a single source of truth with a n↔n relationship. By adding tags, you add a second n↔n relation, and it becomes ambiguous which one should be trusted if data discrepancies appear.

Comment: *entities are likely to be read only 1-2 times after being added*: so we have "thousands being added everyday", let's say 20 000, which means 20 000 to 40 000 of reads per day. This is less than 0.25 to 0.5 reads per second. Doesn't look like it should be your concern: most databases and apps deal with hundreds of requests per second.